# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in testing a web service from java client

Tags: java, security, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, websecurity

**I am testing a web service for registering my data to web service which uses api keys using headers,I get error while using this code**

please help me with this, any answers will be appreciated

```
URL url = new URL("https://xxxxRequest");
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8 ");
    //some headers and params

            OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.write(json.toString());
            os.flush();
            conn.connect();
            recode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

Error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to negotiate the use of secure renegotiation
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:306)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:513)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:207)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Regards

Comment: how can I get the solution fastest for my issue?

Comment: Since you appear to be on Java 8, you can disable this check by setting system property `sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages = true` at least for now. I hope your data is not important or valuable in any way, because a server so old and badly managed it doesn't support rfc5746 will have many other vulnerabilities and your data will very likely be leaked or stolen.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
Is there impact on other things if i change this property

Comment: No. There is a _different_ sysprop to actually _allow_ unsafe renegotiation (instead of only the hello setting) which I _don't_ recommend. Even that would only affect servers that actually DO unsafe reneg, of which there shouldn't be any today, but conceivably there could.

Comment: Thanks.Please write this in answer.I will close this question.